# Cannot use mutating member on immutable value error when modifying a struct

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

I have this simple struct.

```
struct Section {
    let store: Store
    var offers: [Offer]
}
```

In the VC, I have declared an array of these `Section`s at the top like so, `fileprivate var sections: [Section] = []`. And I add some `Section` objects to in the `viewDidLoad()`.

Later, I need to delete some `Offer` objects from the `offers` array inside some `Section`s.

I iterate through the `sections` array to find the `Section` that contains the `Offer` that needs to be deleted.

```
for section in sections {
    if let i = section.offers.index(where: { $0.id == offer.id }) {
        section.offers.remove(at: i) // Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'section' is a 'let' constant
    }
}
```

But when I try to delete that particular `Offer` from the `offers` array, I get the error **Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'section' is a 'let' constant**.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default variables defined in the `for` are `let` and they cannot be altered. So you have to make it a `var.`
Easier solution:

```
for var section in sections {
    if let i = section.offers.index(where: { $0.id == offer.id }) {
        section.offers.remove(at: i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

When you do the for loop of **sections** struct (value type) the **section** variables are immutable. You cannot modify directly their values. You will have to create a mutable version of each Section object, do the modification and assign back to the array (replace the modified object at the right index). For example:

```
sections = sections.map({
    var section = $0
    if let i = section.offers.index(where: { $0.id == offer.id }) {
        section.offers.remove(at: i)
    }
    return section
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `for` loop, the variable is a `let` constant.
To fix it you should use this loop :

```
for index in 0..<sections.count {
    var section = sections[index]
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Since `struct` is a value-type, you need to later update the array with your edited value: `sections[index] = section`

Answer (score 0):

Since reference object on **For loop** is immutable you have to make an intermediate variable on which you have to play logic.

Also you are **using value typed (Structure)** you have to update on datasource from intermediate variable when you are done.

```
for j in 0 ..< sections.count {

    var section = sections[j]

    if let i = section.offers.index(where: { $0.id == offer.id }) {

        aSection.offers.remove(at: i) // Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'section' is a 'let' constant
        sections[j] = section
    }
}
```